# Oracle SQL to return name, count1, percent1, count2, percent2 of category

Tags: sql, oracle

I could not figure out how to just add plain text. The help for this editor showed code and per-formatted text I could not get anything to line up correctly so I entered the information the best I could.

```
Given Tables:
PRODUCT                 PRODUCT_NAME
PROD_ID PROD_IND    PROD_NAM_ID PROD_NAME
1           G           1       apples
2           B           2       oranges
3           B           3       bananas
4           G           4       pears
5           B           5       plums
1           B       
2           G       
3           B       
4           B       
5           G       


I need an Oracle SQL query that will return a row for each grouped
PRODUCT_NAME.PROD_NAME:

Product #Bad Percentage #Good Percentage

apples  1   50           1    50

oranges 1   50           1    50

bananas 2   100          0    0

pears   1   50           1    50

plums   1   50           1    50


Where PRODUCT.PROD_IND = B means Bad and PRODUCT.PROD_IND = G means Good And
Percentage is percentage of total of a PRODUCT_NAME.PROD_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, and see if it works.

```
SELECT x.name,
    x.GoodCount,
    x.GoodCount * 100 /(x.GoodCount + x.BadCount) [GoodPercent],
    x.BadCount,
    x.BadCount * 100 /(x.GoodCount + x.BadCount) [BadPercent]
FROM (
    SELECT pn.PROD_NAME as [name],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN p.PROD_IND = 'G' THEN 1 END) [GoodCount],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN p.PROD_IND = 'B' THEN 1 END) [BadCount]
    FROM PRODUCT as p
    JOIN PRODUCT_NAME as pn ON p.PROD_ID = pn.PROD_NAM_ID
    GROUP BY pn.PROD_NAME 
) as x
```

Comment: you are too nice, all I would have provided is the functions he needs, not the complete query.

Comment: @SaUce but, only lengthy(!) complete answers are accepted! Hard truth!

Comment: @OracleUser I understand that, I just hate to encourage lazy.

Comment: @SaUce I agree, have too much time on my hand. Need to find a new hobby.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for problem:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58b7c/20

```
with counter as (select prod_id, count(*) co from product group by prod_id),
   good_counter as (select prod_id, count(*) co from product where prod_ind='G' group by prod_id),
   bad_counter as (select prod_id, count(*) co from product where prod_ind='B' group by prod_id)
select 
product_name.prod_name, 
coalesce(bad_counter.co,0) "#bad",
coalesce(bad_counter.co,0) / counter.co * 100 bad_percentage, 
coalesce(good_counter.co,0) "#good", 
coalesce(good_counter.co,0) / counter.co * 100 good_percentage
from product_name
  inner join counter on product_name.prod_nam_id=counter.prod_id 
  left join good_counter on counter.prod_id=good_counter.prod_id
  left join bad_counter on counter.prod_id=bad_counter.prod_id
```

There are surely more elegant ways to achieve it. Right?